# VeeValidate 4 Field Validation State

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vee-validate

I'm trying to imitate [Bootstrap form validation styling](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#validation) with Vue and Vee-validate.

In order to have that Boostrap validation error message, when there's a validation error, the input itself must have `is-invalid` class presents. And in addition, the error message element must have `invalid-feedback` class, of course.

I'm struggling to add `is-invalid` class to the input when there's a validation error.

In Vee-validate 3, I was able to control the input element's classes with [this guide](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3/guide/state.html#flags). But it seems to be deprecated.

[This](https://codesandbox.io/s/vee-validate-basic-example-forked-v77oqx?file=/src/App.vue) is a code sandbox that you can play with. Nothing extra-ordinary, just straight out of [Veevalidate example](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/tutorials/basics).

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Form @submit="onSubmit">
      <Field name="email" type="email" :rules="validateEmail" class="form-control"/>
      <ErrorMessage class="invalid-feedback" name="email" />
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Sign up</button>
    </Form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import {
    Form,
    Field,
    ErrorMessage
  } from "vee-validate";

  export default {
    components: {
      Form,
      Field,
      ErrorMessage,
    },
    methods: {
      onSubmit(values) {
        console.log(values, null, 2);
      },
      validateEmail(value) {
        // if the field is empty
        if (!value) {
          return "This field is required";
        }

        // if the field is not a valid email
        const regex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
        if (!regex.test(value)) {
          return "This field must be a valid email";
        }

        // All is good
        return true;
      },
    },
  };
</script>

<style>
  span {
    display: block;
    margin: 10px 0;
  }
</style>
```

### Versions

1. "vee-validate": "^4.5.11",
2. "vue": "^3.2.33",

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can render more complex fields, by utilizing the scoped slots of the `<Field />`-component.

If you replace your Field-component with the following, it should work as expected:

```
<Field name="email" :rules="validateEmail" v-slot="{ field, errors }">
  <input v-bind="field" type="email" :class="{'is-invalid': !!errors.length }" />
</Field>
```

Comment: That helped! Thanks for clearing that up. Actually they [documented](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/guide/components/validation#displaying-error-messages) it. At first glance it was overwhelming compared to previous version, thus hard to see it right away